# Install Notepad++ with Context Menu Option

Tags: powershell, silent-install

I've been working on a script to install notepad++ on some remote servers. We don't have PowerShell Remoting enabled for our environment, so I'm using PSexec to install. Here is the code:

```
& .\psexec.exe -c -e -v -h \\$computer ".\npp.7.5.6.installer.x64.exe" /S
```

This works fine and dandy to actually install the program, but for some reason it doesn't add the context menu option to `Edit with Notepad++` when I right click on a file

I've tried following the instructions [from the Notepad++ wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Explorer_Context_Menu) to add the menu option, but they didn't work. All of the other solutions I've read seem to want me to edit the registry in strange ways, which I am loathe to do.

I'm not exactly sure what's going on with my install, but it seems to install it with the minimalist options instead of the default custom options.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to install it with that context menu option? Is there some kind of switch I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the notepad++ shortcut to the default user SendTo folder and then use right click send to, if all else failed you.

Putting that in the default user profile, should ensure all new users get it, but they'd have to be told to use the right click sendto option since it would not show on the default list.

Any existing user profile, you'd have to manually add to their sendto folder.

Otherwise, you are back to reg hacking to get it on the default menu.[image]